# Table doesn't get value because value is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, undefined

I'm trying do a bidding in my table with returned datas in Angular. But props values is undefined.

My Component:

```
export class EquipmentsComponent implements OnInit {

  form: any;
  titleForm!: string;
  equipments!: Equipments[];

  constructor(private EquipmentService: EquipmentsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

      this.EquipmentService.Getall().subscribe(result => {
      this.equipments = result;
    });
  }
```

My service:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EquipmentsService {
  url = "https://localhost:5001/api/Equipment";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   Getall(): Observable<Equipments[]>{
    return this.http.get<Equipments[]>(this.url);
  }


  GetWithId(EquipmentsID: number): Observable<Equipments>
  {
    const Url = `${this.url}/${EquipmentsID}`;
    return this.http.get<Equipments>(Url);
  }
  PostEquipment(equipment: Equipments ): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<Equipments>(this.url, equipment, httpOptions);
  }
  PutEquipment(equipment: Equipments): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.put<Equipments>(this.url, equipment,httpOptions);
  }

  DeleteEquipment(equipmentId: number): Observable<any>
  {
    const Url = `${this.url}/${equipmentId}`;
    return this.http.delete<Number>(Url, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

My interface:

```
 export interface Equipments{
         EquipmentsID: number;
         Name: string;
         SerialNumber: string;
         Voltage: string;
         ElectricCurrent: string;
         Oil: string;
         Date: Date;
    }
```

My HTML:

```html
<mat-card >
    <div>
      <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary">New Equipment</button>
    </div>
      <hr/>

      <table class="w-100"  *ngIf="equipments">
        <h2>Gerenciar</h2>

        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          <th>Voltage</th>
          <th>Eletric Current</th>
          <th>Oil</th>
          <th>Date Register</th>
          <th>Actions</th>

        </tr>


        <tr  *ngFor="let equip of equipments">
          <td>{{equip.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{equip.SerialNumber}}</td>
          <td>{{equip.Voltage}}</td>
          <td>{{equip.ElectricCurrent}}</td>
          <td>{{equip.Oil}}</td>
          <td>{{equip.Date}}</td>
          <td>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="Click(equip)" color="accent" >Update</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="Clickstring(this.equip.Name)"  >Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </mat-card>
```

My debug:

[image: My image of debug]

I receive my Equipment object with datas of DB, but values as `equipments.Name`, `Equipments.SerialNumber` and etc. Is returned undefined.

My page:

[image: My page]

My page didn't show datas but show buttons and I debug with them, if I clicked in a update return a object with all of prop, and when is clicked in delete show values in a prop as image debug shows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td>{{equip.name}}</td>
```

All your property names are pascal but it should be Camel case

just start the property name with a small case.

Answer (score 0):

Js/Ts is case sensitive, so **equip.name** is note the same as **equip.Name**.

According to your debug image you seem to be receiving the properties from your API in lowercase but you interface has Uppercase. I don't see any mapping for those in you code aswell. So try changing your interface to:

```
 export interface Equipments{
     equipmentsID: number;
     name: string;
     serialNumber: string;
     voltage: string;
     electricCurrent: string;
     oil: string;
     date: Date;
}
```

and your table accordingly

```
<td>{{equip.name}}</td>
<td>{{equip.serialNumber}}</td>
<td>{{equip.voltage}}</td>
<td>{{equip.electricCurrent}}</td>
<td>{{equip.oil}}</td>
<td>{{equip.date}}</td>
```